# Replace of Customize PerspectiveSwitcher Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I want to remove or disable the menuitems "Customize..." and "Save as..." or maybe remove the contextmenu as a whole. (See attached picture)

Do you have an idea on how to disable or remove it?
[image: menu]

Thx

Comment: Why do you want to do so anyway

Comment: These appears to be hard coded in the `PerspectiveSwitcher` class, so they can't easily be removed.